# Unable to find class in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

As someone who has been programming in node.js for a while, finding a specific class has been tough and documentation online has been confusing for someone like me who hasn't had much experience with package dependency in Java.

First off, this is the command I am trying to run

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="gifClass"`

I put a file called gifClass.java (with the class name being gifClass) in both the highest part of the project directory and the src folder. Nevertheless, I get a `classNotFoundException: gifClass`

Can anyone help me coming from node.js? Thanks!

Comment: how does your dir structure look like ?

Comment: You should pass the fully qualified name of the Java class like `$mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.daniel.demo.gifClass"` just make sure you replace the package name with the one in your code...

Comment: Regarding Java language code conventions you should also have a look at [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) - this is not necessarily related to your question but it will help you migrating to Java ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your java source files into `src/main/java` directory (this is the root directory for Java sources, use subdirectories for Java packages).

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html